# How do I evaluate a nested object data to apply a css class

Tags: twig, conditional-statements

Using the data below (links) below teh Twig logic is checking the 'link' level names to compare an argument passed to the macro. This applies an 'active' class to the appropriate list item. Unfortunately, I don't know how to also check the 'sublinks' as a 'sublink' value may be the one that matches the argument passed to the macro.  I need to be able to also check 'sublinks' and apply 'active' if it is a 'sublink' (rather than a 'link') which is == currentPage.

```
{% set
links = {
    'home': ['home', 'Home'],

    'hotel-reviews': ['hotel-reviews', 'Hotel Reviews'],    

    'pages': {
        name: 'Pages',
        sublinks: {
            'about':         ['samples/about', 'About Us'],
            'register':      ['samples/register', 'Register'],
            'error':         ['error', 'Error Page'],
            '404':           ['404', '404 Page'],
        },
    },
    'portfolio': {
        name: 'Portfolio',
        sublinks: {
            'portfolio': ['portfolio/portfolio', 'Portfolio'],
            'project': ['portfolio/project', 'Project'],
        },
    },
    'blog': {
        name: 'Blog',
        sublinks: {
            'blog': ['blog/blog', 'Blog'],
            'post': ['blog/post', 'Blog Post'],
        },
    },

    'ui-elements': ['ui-elements', 'UI Elements'],



}   

%}

{% set currentPage = this.page.id  %} 


{% macro render_menu(links, currentPage) %}

{% import _self as subnav %}

{% for code, link in links %}

    <li class="{{ (code == currentPage)  ? 'active' }}  {{ link.sublinks ? 
'dropdown' }}">

        <a
            href="{{ link.sublinks ? '#' : (link.page ?: link[0])|page }}"
            {% if link.sublinks %}data-toggle="dropdown"{% endif %}
            class="{{ link.sublinks ? 'dropdown-toggle' }}"
        >
            {{ link.name ?: link[1] }}
            {% if link.sublinks %}<span class="caret"></span>{% endif %}
        </a>
        {% if link.sublinks %}
            <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {{ subnav.render_menu(link.sublinks) }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}



    </li>
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as nav %}


<nav id="layout-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" 
 role="navigation">
    <div class="container">



    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ 'home'|page }}">Taiga Travel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {{ nav.render_menu(links, currentPage) }} 


            <li>
                <button

                    class="btn btn-sm navbar-btn btn-primary navbar-right 
hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    Sign in
                </button>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is hard to answer as we don't know how your child pages are related to their parent at this point. The most "simple" solution would be to resort to an array `currentPages` and store (all) the active pages in there. Then u would be able to do `{{ page.id in currentPages ? 'active }}`

Answer (score 0):

After much head scratching, I figured I'd try to loop through the sublinks checking for the 'currentPage' and it seems to have worked:

```
{% set
    links = {
        'home': ['home', 'Home'],

        'hotel-reviews': ['hotel-reviews', 'Hotel Reviews'],    

        'pages': {
            name: 'Pages',
            sublinks: {
                'about':         ['samples/about', 'About Us'],
                'register':      ['samples/register', 'Register'],
                'error':         ['error', 'Error Page'],
                '404':           ['404', '404 Page'],
            },
        },
        'portfolio': {
            name: 'Portfolio',
            sublinks: {
                'portfolio': ['portfolio/portfolio', 'Portfolio'],
                'project': ['portfolio/project', 'Project'],
            },
        },
        'blog': {
            name: 'Blog',
            sublinks: {
                'blog': ['blog/blog', 'Blog'],
                'post': ['blog/post', 'Blog Post'],
            },
        },

        'ui-elements': ['ui-elements', 'UI Elements'],
    }   

%}

{% set currentPage = this.page.id  %} 

{% macro render_menu(links, currentPage) %}

    {% import _self as subnav %}

    {% for code, link in links %}

        <li class="

            {% if link.sublinks %}

                {% for sub, sublink in link.sublinks %}

                    {{ (sub == currentPage)  ? 'active' }}  {{ link.sublinks ? 'dropdown' }} 

                {% endfor %}

            {% else %}

                {{ (code == currentPage)  ? 'active' }}  {{ link.sublinks ? 'dropdown' }}

            {% endif %}"
        >

            <a
                href="{{ link.sublinks ? '#' : (link.page ?: link[0])|page }}"
                {% if link.sublinks %}data-toggle="dropdown"{% endif %}
                class="{{ link.sublinks ? 'dropdown-toggle' }}"
            >
                {{ link.name ?: link[1] }}
                {% if link.sublinks %}<span class="caret"></span>{% endif %}
            </a>
            {% if link.sublinks %}
                <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    {{ subnav.render_menu(link.sublinks, currentPage) }}

                </ul>
            {% endif %}

        </li>

    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as nav %}


<nav id="layout-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ 'home'|page }}">Taiga Travel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {{ nav.render_menu(links, currentPage) }} 

                <li>
                    <button

                        class="btn btn-sm navbar-btn btn-primary navbar-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                        Sign in
                    </button>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```